# Convert list of lists (with indexes) to csr matrix

Tags: python, scipy

I have a list of lists

```
[[1, 6, 1.0],
[4, 20, 2.0],
[10, 29, 4.5],
etc...]
```

I need to convert that into a csr matrix. However, the first two elements of every list are the indexes.

Comment: We might be able to help you better if you could tell us what a CSR matrix is

Comment: Have a look at this answer, I think it solves your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32800395/create-csr-matrix-from-x-index-y-index-value?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Steve suggested in a comment, take a look at my answer here: [Create CSR matrix from x_index, y_index, value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32800395/create-csr-matrix-from-x-index-y-index-value?rq=1)

You can use `zip` to unpack your list of lists into the row indices, column indices and values.  For example:

```
In [307]: from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

In [308]: ll = [[0, 0, 1.0], [1, 2, 2.0], [4, 5, 3.0], [5, 5, 4.0], [5, 6, 5.0]]

In [309]: rows, cols, vals = zip(*ll)

In [310]: a = csr_matrix((vals, (rows, cols)))

In [311]: a.A
Out[311]: 
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  2.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  3.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  4.,  5.]])
```